# Prove that perimeter of triangle $MNC$ is equal to half perimeter of triangle $ABC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In $ABC$ equilateral triangle. $K$ is midpoint of $AB$. $M$ and $N$ lie on $AC$ and $BC$ respectively. If $\angle MKN=60°$, then prove that perimeter of $\triangle MNC$ is equal to half perimeter of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Could you please include your attempt?

Comment: I have attempted to solve this problem for some hours. Unfortunately I did not get anything noteworthy.

Comment: I agree that but this not the way the site works. At least attach a neat figure and show whatever you have done. This not an exam that you will lose your marks for wrong solutions. Might be possible that you are on verge to get the answer and need only a hint and we may directly address your problem.

Comment: I found a fairly straightforward solution using only similar triangles and the law of cosines to express all sides in terms of only the length of $AM$ but I would think that there must be more pretty solutions considering the simplicity of the problem

Comment: Don't worry. I'm sure your alternative solution will be fine as an answer, even if it was not the intended answer that the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
First look at the left picture.

Mirror $N$ with respect to $CK$, let it be $N'$. We notice that $\angle CN'N=\angle MKN=60^{\circ}$. Therefore $MKNN'$ are co-cyclic. Therefore $\triangle MKN$'s mirror image with respect to $CK$ shares the same circumcircle with $\triangle MKN$. Therefore the center of $\triangle MKN$'s circumcircle lies on $CK$.

Now draw angle bisectores of $\angle CMN, \angle CNM$ and let them meet at $I$. Obviously $I$ lies on the third bisector $CK$. Since $\angle MIN=120^{\circ}$, $M,K,N,I$ are co-cyclic. Furthermore, combining with the result from previous paragraph, we know $IK$ is a diameter of that circle. Therefore $\angle IMK=\angle INK=90^{\circ}$.

Hence $MK$ bisects the outer angle $\angle AMN$ and $NK$ bisects the outer angle $\angle BNM$.

Now look at the right picture. Draw the circle tangent to $AM,MN,NB$ and let its center be $O$. We will notice that $MO$ will bisect the angle $AMN$ and $NO$ will bisect the angle $BNM$ so $O$ and $K$ are essentially the same point.

Now its easy to see the perimeter of $\triangle CMN$ is same as $CP+CQ$, which is half the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$. (Because $AP={1\over 2} AK={1\over 4}AB$ and so does $BQ$)

Comment: Very nice solution, but there is a more elementary way to establish the conclusion about bissecting outer angles. Angle chasing tells you that triangles $AMK$ and $BKN$ are similar, and then by $|MK| / |KN| = |AM| / |BK| = |AM| / |AK|$ we find that triangle $KMN$ is similar to those as well, proving the claim.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative way. Indeed with angle chasing on $MKNI$ we can immediately calculate that $MNK$ is half $MNB$. I guess I am more of a intuitive geometry thinker than using algebraic calculation to solve geometric problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem guys!

[image]

Let's take point $P$ at side $BC$ where $\angle NKP=60°$.  Then take point $T$ at PK line where $PK=KT$. Triangles $BKP$ and $ATK$ are congruent. So $\angle TAK=60°=\angle KBP$. Notice that $AMKT$ is a circumcircle. So  $\angle TAK=\angle TMK$. Thus $TMK$ is an equilateral triangle.

Now we can be sure that triangles $MKN$ and $NKP$ are congruent. So $MN=NK$. By Ptolemy's theorem, we obtain that $AM+AT=AK$. Also, don't forget that $BP=AT$.

$CM+AM+AK=CM+2AK-AT=CM+BC-BP=CM+CP=CM+CN+NP=CM+CN+MN$.

Comment: My way of writing the solution is a bit crude. But I hope you will understand it

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding a diagram in your answer.

Comment: Of course i don't mind